# Pop up spheres in web page using CSS3 / HTML5

Tags: html, css

I am designing a web app in whose log in page, I would like to pop up filled spheres in the sequence 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 as given in the following (crudely) drawn representation.

[image]

I have just used plain HTML before and very little CSS. So I am very new to HTML5 and CSS3. Any help from you guys will be really appreciated.

Thanks,
EG

Comment: I reckon there are several ways to do this... so what is the question?

Comment: A working example will be good. I'll really appreciate it :)

Comment: are you just looking for a way to draw spheres?

Comment: Not drawing them. Popping them one after other or at random. And they don't have to be spheres. They can be squares or of any other shape too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/BwBzn/1/)

tested in firefox and chrome:

use transition delay in your css

```
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
-moz-transition-delay: 0.5s;
```

for more information see this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp):